# Issue removing multiple duplicate lines from a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to remove duplicate lines from a text file and keep facing issues... The output file keeps putting the first two accounts on the same line. Each account should have a different line... Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as f:
    unique_lines = set(f.readlines())
with open('accounts_No_Dup.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(unique_lines)
```

accounts.txt:

```
@account1
@account2
@account3
@account4
@account5
@account6
@account7
@account5
@account8
@account4
```

accounts_No_Dup.txt:

```
@account4@account3
@account4
@account8
@account5
@account7
@account1
@account2
@account6
```

print(unique_lines)

```
{'@account4', '@account7\n', '@account3\n', '@account6\n', '@account5\n', '@account8\n', '@account4\n', '@account2\n', '@account1\n'}
```

Comment: post result of `unique_lines`

Comment: please post the file `'accounts.txt'` *itself* I suspect this has to do with invisible characters

Comment: I can't replicate.

Comment: I have edited and added accounts.txt, unique_lines and accounts_No_Dup.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `set` changes the order of your lines and your last element doesn't end with `\n` as you don't have an empty line at the end of your file.

Just add the separator or don't use `set`.

```
with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as f:
    unique_lines = set()
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line.endswith('\n'):
            line += '\n'
        unique_lines.add(line)


with open('accounts_No_Dup.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(unique_lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

The last line in your file is missing a newline (technically a violation of [POSIX standards for text files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file#Unix_text_files), but so common you have to account for it), so `"@account4\n"` earlier on is interpreted as unique relative to `"@account4"` at the end. I'd suggest unconditionally stripping newlines, and adding them back when writing:

```
with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as f:
    unique_lines = {line.rstrip("\r\n") for line in f}  # Remove newlines for consistent deduplication
with open('accounts_No_Dup.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(f'{line}\n' for line in unique_lines)  # Add newlines back
```

By the by, on modern Python (CPython/PyPy 3.6+, 3.7+ for any interpreter), you can preserve order of first appearance by using a `dict` rather than a `set`. Just change the read from the file to:

```
    unique_lines = {line.rstrip("\r\n"): None for line in f}
```

and you'll see each line the first time it appears, in that order, with subsequent duplicates being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using `unique` keyword

The code is as below

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('d:\\test.txt', sep="/n", header=None)
df =  pd.DataFrame(data[0].unique())

with open('d:\\testnew.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(df.to_string(header = False, index = False)))
```

Results: Test file to read has data

[image]

The result is it removed the duplicate lines

[image]

Comment: Introducing Pandas (a ridiculously heavyweight framework, especially when you include all of its dependencies) to solve a trivial problem is *massive* overkill.